# Woocommerce pass custom values to checkout process

Tags: php, variables, woocommerce, checkout

I have performed some custom calculations using custom fields in the cart and now need to use these value to go through the payment process. I can replicate the calculations in the checkout but then I cant pass this custom amount through to the payment gateway. Any ideas on how to do this?

Can I not create a custom pay now button that goes through to the payment method with the custom price passed or something?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, you should add all related code calculation and custom fields editing your question. Without that you will get irrelevant answers… Your question is just unclear for now and stackOverflow is based on code help… More effort you make in having a clean detailed and complete question, more chances you get to have useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the filter `woocommerce_checkout_fields`. You can add fields there to use in the checkout.

[Adding custom shipping and billing fields](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-6)